# Pass data from Class to Viewcontroller in swift iOS

Tags: swift, uikit

I am wanting to pass **var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?** in **Class Audio** to func **playAudioIfNeeded** in **MainViewController** .

I want the **func playAudioIfNeeded** in **MainViewController** to be able to call the AVPlayerLayer library.

Hope can you help me !

My expectations:

```
func playVideoIfNeeded() {
   playerLayer.play()
}
```

My current code is below

Audio.swift

```
class Audio: UIView {

   var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?

}
```

AudioCollectionViewCell.swift

```
 class AudioCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

 @IBOutlet private weak var audioView: Audio!

   func configure(contentID: String) {
        videoView.startVideo(contentID: contentID)
    }
}
```

MainCell.swift

```
class HairstyleDetailCell: UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeue(type: AudioCollectionViewCell.self, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.configure(contentID: "11111")
     return cell
}
```

MainViewController.swift

```
func playAudioIfNeeded() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## This isn't an "exact" answer

Without seeing all of your code, this is a difficult question to answer with exactness. However, what you seek to do is a common thing in mobile development. For a long time, `UIKit` has used a pattern called [`Delegation`](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/delegation-in-swift/) to solve this.

It's not a difficult topic, but it can be confusing the first time around. So I'll do my best to explain it.

## Delegation

If you are the manager at a job, you may delegate tasks to subordinates. Similarly, we can create that relationship in our code. One class may own the decision-making of *when* to do something, and the other class may own the *how* it gets done.

You've already come across this by using a collection view. The Collection view tells the host controller when to load the cells via delegation.

Here is a very simple example.

```swift
// Define the delegate's interface
protocol RadioDelegate {
    func play(_ song: String)
}

// create the class that adheres to the delegate protocol
class Speaker: RadioDelegate {
    let radio: Radio
    
    init(_ radio: Radio) {
        self.radio = radio
        radio.delegate = self // assign the delegate to the manager
    }

    func play(_ song: String) {
        AVPlayer.play(song)
    }
}

// create the manager class
class Radio {
    // make a variable to hold a delegate
    var delegate: RadioDelegate?
    
    var selectedSong = ""
    
    func tapPlayButton() {
        delegate?.play(selectedSong) // delegate the work
    }
}
```